# Any open source Facebook library that handles authentication and wall posts for ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to implement two pieces of functionality to my ASP.NET MVC 3 applications.

1. I would like the ability for the user to use Facebook Connect to authenticate on my web site. I would also like to be able to store the users name and email in my database upon successful login.
2. I would like to post to the users wall once a certain event occurs.

For the first item I worked with DotNetOpenAuth and managed to get it working successfully. But I am not sure how the get the second item done. More importantly, are there any open source libraries that can handle both tasks out there?

Thanks

Comment: The [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) should be able to do them both. You've even tagged it in your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook C# SDK can do this for you. Check here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

check out the facebook packages in nuget - facebook-mvc I think it is.